# cURL Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed, but nghttp2 is installed

Tags: 20.04, curl, aws

I'm trying to setup the wallet RPC for a Monero node, but when I use cURL to that port, I get this error:

```
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
```

However, checking `curl --version` gives me this:

```
curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1f zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.40.0 librtmp/2.3
```

I thought that error would only present when cURL was compiled without nghttp2. This is an AWS environment, running 20.04.

Comment: Had the problem hitting on a Python `http.server`.

Comment: I had this error when using `http` instead of `https` to request the server with `curl`, so maybe try using `https`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would be great to see exactly your complete `curl` request.
HTTP/0.9 is from 1991, previous to the basic HTTP/1.0 so I think that the problem is the response from the Server.

Please try:

1. Your `curl` command with the `--verbose` parameter so it outputs all the information.
2. Try the same URL you attempt with `curl` with `wget` and what are the contents of the file saved. Do if from inside a new empty folder.
3. telnet to that port and type:

   ```
   GET / HTTP/1.0<ENTER>
   <ENTER>
   ```

   where `<ENTER>` is just pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and see the output. Maybe you are trying to open the wrong port.
4. Some times the problem is in the certificate. Try with the parameters:

   ```
   --ssl
   --sslv2
   --sslv3
   ```
5. You can also enforce:

   ```
   --http1.1
   --http2
   ```

Also your organization or ISP may be using a transparent proxy which is catching the request or that is using a SSL certificate causing problems.

Comment: I would have never assumed the port they said to use, in their own documentation, would be the wrong one, but here we are.

Comment: Yes, is very disappointing, but those things happen. One day they decide to change the port and nobody realizes that documentation is obsolete. Maybe the good Engineer that was doing that excellent work leaved. Glad the problem is fixed for you! :) Cheers

Comment: Beware that docker recommends a secure deployment, therefore the first thing you should check is the protocol, as many tutorial still use http.

Comment: Hello @CarlesMateo, I am also facing similar issue. I am getting "curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed, and hence HA PROXY is not able to send requests to this Server" error. I have posted my question on "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76304814/how-to-create-a-http-service-in-shellscript-via-xinetd-service-for-readwrite-ha"

Answer (score 20):

```
curl --http0.9
```

will help you out. I got that same error message after upgrading `curl`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since this is the way to deal with a HTTP0.9 request in curl.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the same error from curl and it turned out it was an ftp server...

So for the ones who came here searching for "***curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed***" try this on a browser:

```
ftp://IP:PORT
```

Or this on a terminal:

```
ftp IP PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl --http2-prior-knowledge 'your_host'
```

may help if you are trying to request an HTTP/2 webserver without HTTP/1.1 upgrade ([curl docs](https://curl.se/docs/http2.html#:%7E:text=curl%20offers%20the%20%2D%2Dhttp2%2Dprior%2Dknowledge)).

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to connect to an ESMTP mail server - verify this by trying telnet to the same address and port to view the ESMTP greeting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).